# Advice on type of analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, multivariate-analysis

I do not have much experience in statistics, so I am reaching here for advice. Just feeling a bit lost to start with!

I have data on 100 trees, for each of which I have the following attributes: presence-absence of attribute 1 (binary variable), damage (attribute 4 with four categories), and measurements of attribute 2 and 3 (continuous variables). The tentative response variable is attribute 3. Below, I have added a summary table of mean values of attributes 2 and 3. Blanks mean no measurements.

[image]

First, I am interested to know which attributes are the ones that most influence the values of attribute 3 (attribute 1, attribute 2 and attribute 4). Then, I would like to look at whether the values of attribute 3 are statistically larger when (a) attribute 1 is absent, and/or (b) attribute 2 is absent.

I would appreciated any guidance in what statistical approaches I can implement to answer my questions (I will be using R)!

Comment: Your table is very difficult to interpret. Let me get this straight: your response variable is Attribute 3 (which we will call y -- this appears to be continuous). You have the following variables where you want to know their effect on y: Attribute 1 (dummy variable), Attribute 2 (dummy variable), Attribute 4 (continuous variable). Is this a correct interpretation of the question?

Comment: Hi! Sorry if my way of summarising my data wasn't clear. I've simplified the table now. Let me know if putting a sample of the raw data would be better. Attribute 3 is a continuous response variable (variable y). Attributes 1 (binary) and 2 (continuous) are dummy variables), and attribute 4 is categorical (four categories).

Comment: I would always recommend giving sample data in the future when asking questions, because it helps answerers visualize your problem, and importantly understand if there are any quirks in your data that might make a standard approach unadvisable. For now, I answered your question with the information provided. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are primarily interested in the effects of your covariates, I would recommend an OLS model due to the high degree of interpretability. The mathematical regression specification would be the following:

$Attribute_{3i} = \alpha + \beta_1*Atribute_{1i}+\beta_2*Attribute_{2i}+\beta_3*Attribute_{4i}$

An implementation of this in R would look roughly like the following:

```
reg <- lm(Attribute3 ~ Attribute1 + Attribute2 + Attribute4, data = data)
summary(reg)
```

The significance of the terms will tell you their individual impact and answer your questions. That being said, you should look into the assumptions of OLS and how to properly validate your model (i.e. residual analysis, etc.) to make sure the approach is ultimately valid and your coefficients are unbiased.

**However**, I will caveat that since you have a continuous variable and two dummy variables, you should avoid some sort of conclusion of "which effect is biggest/most influential" when looking at your coefficient estimates. Usually, for variable importance, you would need to standardize your explanatory variables so they could be properly compared. However, you can't really "standardize" dummy variables for this approach. [Here is a quick primer I found from a quick google search](https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/identifying-important-independent-variables/) on Variable Importance.

Comment: The beta coefficients will determine the impact of individual covariates on the dependent variable only if they are standardized.

Comment: Standardization is not necessary to determine individual covariate impact on the dependent variable, and non-standardized inputs will accomplish most of what he wants (such as whether the values of Attribute 3 are statistically different when Attributes 1/2 are present or not). It is, however, necessary to get variable importance (i.e. answer the question of "which attributes are the ones that most influence the value of Attribute 3)